# Use env variable to represent SSH options

Tags: ssh, environment-variables

These two ssh options:

```
 ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o NumberOfPasswordPrompts=0
```

I am interested in setting those using env variables, is there a way to do that?

```
export StrictHostKeyChecking=no 
export NumberOfPasswordPrompts=0
```

but that's of course not quite right

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "proper" way to do this is within your `~/.ssh/config` file, where you can make those global for all connections or you can restrict it by host (or a few more advanced things). I'm going to assume you can't do that but that you do still have the ability to alter your `~/.bashrc` or whatever.

You can solve this by putting this in your `~/.bashrc` or `~/.zshrc` (or by running these lines before `ssh`):

```sh
SSH_ARGS=( -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o NumberOfPasswordPrompts=0 )
alias ssh='ssh "${SSH_ARGS[@]}"'
```

If you want explicit environment variables like what you're proposing in your question (e.g. `$StrictHostKeyChecking`) then you'll have to make a really ugly alias or function to convert them all to the final `ssh` call. Here's a solution that should work in bash but won't work in POSIX shell:

```sh
ssh() {
  local SSH_VAR SSH_VAR_VALUE
  for SSH_VAR in StrictHostKeyChecking NumberOfPasswordPrompts; do # expand this
    SSH_VAR_VALUE="${!SSH_VAR}" # bash indirect expansion
    if [ -n "$SSH_VAR_VALUE" ]; then
      set -- -o "$SSH_VAR=$SSH_VAR_VALUE" "$@"
    fi
  done
  command ssh "$@"
}
```

The above example only supports the two SSH variables named in the question. That line will likely have to get really long as it must explicitly name every option before the semicolon on the line with the `# expand this` comment.

This loops over every supported SSH variable and uses [bash's indirect expansion](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/41293/87770) to check whether it is in the environment (and not an empty value). If it is, a `-o` and the option name and its value are prepended to the start of the argument list (`$@`).

If you use zsh, you'll need [zsh's parameter expansion flag `P`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/119442/87770), replacing bash's `${!SSH_VAR}` with zsh's `${(P)SSH_VAR}`. Other shells may need to replace that whole "bash indirect expansion" line with `eval "SSH_VAR_VALUE=\"\${$SSH_VAR}\""` (watch your quoting there, or that line can be dangerous).

Invoking `command ssh` prevents the recursion we'd get from calling `ssh` from within a function of the same name. `command ssh` ignores the function and actually runs the true `ssh` command.

Comment: If you are giving up POSIX compatibility by using `${!...}`, why not use an array as well instead of repeatedly calling `set`?

Comment: except putting it in a file would affect everything, and I only want to control the current session

Comment: @chepner – I prefer to use as few bashisms as possible. As you can see from my explanation, I provide a POSIX shell solution using `eval`. @AlexanderMills – you can just paste the lines from either solution into your shell and they'll work for just that session. If you add the second solution to your `~/.bashrc`, it will harmlessly loop through any unset variables and will provide an unmolested `ssh` command when you don't have any of those variables set.